# Unknown JPEG compression technique?

Tags: android, jpeg

Well, so I've been digging through an android game's files trying to get sprites and the like. So I've managed to come across this folder called "raw", and inside were jpg files like imagelocal2.jpg (along with imagelocal2.list) and such. These files aren't valid images and can't be viewed normally, but they're big enough to contain many images inside of them.

What I'm wondering is, is there some unknown JPG compression-like method where they manage to squish a bunch of files into one? I opened the files with a hex editor but I couldn't make heads or tails of them (the fact that I have no experience with hex editors doesn't really help), so if anyone knows anything about how these files are compressed, please help.

Comment: Maybe it's a custom file, storing the image by using the `Base64 encoding`. I used this technique to store an image within a text file.

Comment: Try searching for the first 2-4 bytes of the file in this list: http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard multi-image JPEG format.  it would be anything with a JPG extension. No competently-written decoder would rely on the extension anyway.

You could take a look at the first few bytes and try to match the file signature.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_file_signatures